# Pareto 2d Dual y axis graph, secondary Y axis data incorrectly plotted

Tags: javascript, java, fusioncharts

Im trying to create a pareto2d dual y axis Fusion chart. The primary y axis and x axis data are getting plotted fine. But the values that are being passed for the secondary y axis (cumulative percentage line graph ) is not getting plotted properly. It plots incorrect values for the cumilative percentage. Although the data that is being passed for generating the graph is correct. But while its plotted, it shows incorrect values.

code

```
function(response) {
var myChart = new FusionCharts("FusionCharts/Pareto2D.swf",
chart1Id", "500", "230","0");
myChart.setChartData(response, "xml");
myChart.render("VisifireChart55");
```

In the above code, the setChartData() parameters contains the right values.Even after plotting the graph, the tool tip specifies the right cumilative % values. But the actual values plotted in the graph are incorrect. When I right click and select the option copy to clipboard, and paste it in a notepad, it contains incorrect data for Cumilative percentage. I have also checked the fusion charts faq and verified whether any duplicate attributes are there in the chartxml data . But there is no redundancy. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: How are you plotting a secondary axis in Pareto chart is not clear. Can you please create a dummy data and create a fiddle for better understanding. You also mention about a 'cumulative percentage line'. Are you using Flash version or JavaScript version? Need more details to understand your problem.

Comment: Im using a Flash version for generating the chart. Using Pareto 2d as reference.